# How to display specific elements from an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

For example, 
I have an array and all the elements are 40s. I'd like to bring elements from 0 to 9 when I click a button called aButton. And when I hit mButton,  it brings elements from 10 to 19.

```
 let arr = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28",   "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39"]

@IBAction func aButton(_ sender: Any) {
}

@IBAction func mButton(_ sender: Any) {
}
```

`

```
 @IBAction func aButton(_ sender: Any) {
    displayedElements = numberOfRows.filter {(0...9).contains(Int($0)!)}
}

@IBAction func mButton(_ sender: Any) {
    displayedElements = numberOfRows.filter {(10...19).contains(Int($0)!)}
}

var displayedElements:[String] = [] {
    didSet {
        tableview.reloadData()
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return displayedElements

}
```

I see this error: Cannot convert return expression of type '[String]' to return type 'Int'

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you're trying to achieve. What do you mean by 'display specific elements' and 'bring elements'?

Comment: I meant, to show index from 0 to 9 when I click aButton and when I click mButton, to show index from 10 to 19.

Comment: I have an UITableView. I'd like the array elements that I extracted to show in the tableview.

Comment: Have you set up the `tableView.datasource`? How do those functions look, i.e. how are you currently populating the table?

Comment: Does your issue is resolved?

Comment: No, it's not resolved yet. and I have set up the tableView.datasource.

Comment: What is the data type of numberOfRows?

Comment: it's an array.   var numberOfRows = arr // arr is the array.

Comment: I have use the same code but it is not throwing error to me

Comment: yes, it doesn't show any error but index number from 10 to 19 isn't displayed. not from 0 to 9.. only from 10 to 19.. I'd like the range to be displayed in the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

The filtering you're performing looks like it should work (although I've not tested it) but your datasource needs a little work. The `numberOfRows` function should look like this:-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return displayedElements.count
}
```

I'll assume for now that your `cellForRowAt` function is correctly dereferencing `displayedElements[indexPath.row]` to display the rows.